# COUNT-SQL how to identify duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a simple question but I am unable to find an answer.

My scenario is I have a app and users are downloading it and the database captures the user id, week in which they downloaded and version they downloaded.

This is my table structure

```
downld_time| downld_version| usr_id
00           0.5             A
00           0.5             B
00           0.5             C
 2           1               E
 2           1               F
 3           1.2             F
 4           1.2             E
 5           1.2             A
```

It is easy to find the number of users who downloaded my app using this query

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT usr_id)
FROM download
WHERE 1
```

Now my question is if I want to drill down and see the number of new users that downloaded in week 5,I should get the count as 0 ,because user A already downloaded the app in week 0 and is not a new user.

and also I need to know what week the user A first downloaded his app.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT usr_id)
FROM download
WHERE `downld_time`=5
```

What should I add to the above query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to find users that downloaded app first time in week 5:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT usr_id)
FROM download
WHERE downld_time=5 and usr_id not in (
    SELECT usr_id
    FROM download
    WHERE downld_time < 5
)
```

To find the first week when User A downloaded the app:

```
SELECT MIN(downld_time) where usr_id='A'
```

Comment: You need to change "WHERE downld_time <> 5" to "WHERE downld_time < 5"

Answer (score 0):

To find the number of new users for a given week you can use the following -

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `d1`.`usr_id`)
FROM `download` `d1`
LEFT JOIN `download` `d2`
    ON `d1`.`usr_id` = `d2`.`usr_id`
    AND `d1`.`downld_time` > `d2`.`downld_time`
WHERE `d1`.`downld_time` = 5
AND `d2`.`usr_id` IS NULL
```

The idea here is to join the download table to itself based on the usr_id where the usr does not have a previous entry in the table.